# How to structure the firestore database so that minimum calls are used

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react native, so in my case there is a form, with these fields

Name, school, class, section

In a day there will be multiple entries with same form fields, so how to structure my data so that I can retrieve my data based on date.

Should I create document with id as date+timestamp, and add fields to it on each entry but in this case I will have multiple documents for a single day, or is there any other way I can add only single document for a day and fields on each entry, and also able to fetch it based on date.

Comment: *Should I create document with id as date+timestamp* - no. What's about storing each document in firebase with your fields along with a field with a value timestamp?  For simplicity it could even be a string formatted date, like 20210407. That would be easily queryable and sortable if needed. See [Add data to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* make a single document per day, for example:

Using moment.js for date formatting,

firestore().collection('attendance')
.doc(`${moment().format('D')}${moment().format('M')}${moment().format('y')}`)
.collection('entries')
.add(newEntry)

But, I believe it's not good practice to add these entries as fields on the single document. They should be their own documents in a collection within the day.

E.g.

Attendance Collection > 7April2021 Document > Entries Collection :[tim doc, sarah doc, brian doc, tyler doc]